# Should I mention in my query letter to agents and/or publishers that I'm a minor?

Tags: young-author, traditional-publishing

I'm only on my second draft of a novel I'm writing (the first was about 77k words), but I've been doing my research on what to do when I'm done with all of my drafts. I'm a minor and I want to traditionally publish my novel, but I'm not sure if mentioning in my query letter to agents that I'm a minor is a good idea. Would literary agents think it makes me unique or just unreliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second user482877, don't mention it.

The agent won't give you any extra consideration out of sympathy, their job is to  find publishable work that publishers will enjoy reading, with as few necessary modifications as possible.

The only reason your age matters at all is when it comes to contracts and agreements; if and when the agent calls you, you will know you wrote something worth something. Talk to the agent, but do not sign ***anything,*** even electronically, tell them at that point you are a minor, and your parent or guardian will have to be involved.

A legitimate agent will never charge you anything. If any kind of fee is mentioned, it is a scam. Say "I'm sorry, that sounds like a scam." And hang up. It wasn't real. Shit like that happens.

Typically a query letter includes a few pages, perhaps even 10, not the entire book. If the agent is asking for the full text of your book, hooray. Be sure you have their name, their business address, their phone number, write all that in a note on your computer in a separate file, with the date. There is virtually zero risk an agent will steal your work; but these are "contemporaneous notes", admissible in court, and for your own records, to follow up on with the agent.

You can use the same file for any other agents you send to.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Many agents recommend that you do not mention your age in your query letter because it might unfavourably bias the agent against you. The common suggestion is that you mention your age only when the agent contacts you.